# MongoDB Atlas - Replica Set Has No Primary

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm fairly new to MongoDB (Atlas - free tier), where I have created a project using it for storing my data. I had it set up and working fine for a couple of weeks, when suddenly I received an email with: `An alert is open for your Atlas project: Replica set has no primary`. I have no idea what this means and I don't believe I have done anything in the last couple of days/weeks that could warrant this alert. However, after checking my project, it seems that I can no longer connect to my cluster and access my data.

After checking on MongoDB Cloud, it seems that my cluster has stopped working and only the secondary shard (don't know if this is the right terminology) is running, while the other two seem to be down. Can anyone explain what this means, why it is happening or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Review server logs for clues, add last day of logs for each server to the question.

Comment: How can I access server logs?

Answer (score 3):

To troubleshoot issues like this, read the server logs and act based on the information therein.

For free and shared tiers in Atlas the logs are apparently [not](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongodb-logs) [available](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations#std-label-atlas-free-tier). Therefore:

- For a free tier cluster (M0), delete this cluster and create a new one. If you don't have a backup you should be able to dump via a direct connection to any of the operational secondary nodes or using the secondary read preference.
- For a shared tier cluster (M2/M5), use the official MongoDB support channels for assistance.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a reason for receiving this alert? Or is this hard to determine without the server logs?

Comment: Reason for the alert is your cluster has no primary. Reason for your cluster to not have a primary I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same alert from Mongo. Looks like there is an issue with their infrastructure.

Response from the support team:

`There appears to be an issue with the underlying infrastructure which our team is currently aware of.`